# Is there any purpose of splitting up express and app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I see these two lines in ( every ?) Express app.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
```

I have to wonder if any parameters can be passed to `express()`?

Checked here and did not see any

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html

Why are some methods on express() and some on app()?

It seems like they should be combined and have all methods on one object.

Comment: When all else fails, [check the code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js#L37) - spoiler alert, it doesn't take any other parameters. I'm not quite sure what the question is because of course the express object has a purpose, you use it to setup all your routes, start the server etc.

Comment: My question was worded wrong.  There are methods on both express and app.  Code like this were you have to use both lines seems odd to me.  For example, is there anything useful I can do with out creating app?  Is there anything I can do only with express?

Comment: @J.M. - I've updated my answer to try to address that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`express`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express) does not take any parameters, no. The purpose of calling it is to create the app object, so the fact you have to call it does make sense, even without parameters.

Another way you often see that written is:

```
const app = require("express")();
```

It'll need to be separate again when using ESM, though.

```
import express from "express"; // Or similar

const app = express();
```

---

In a comment you've said:

> For example, is there anything useful I can do with out creating app? Is there anything I can do only with express?

As far as I know, you have to have create at least one Application object to do anything useful with Express. Note that you don't have to create just *one* app. That's the typical use case, but there's no reason you can't create multiple apps running on different ports.

You may be wondering why express can't just give you an Application object directly from `require`. The reason is that modules are only loaded once and cached, so what you get from `require` is shared. So Express exports the `express` function, which you use to create the Application object (or objects, plural, if you want more than one).

Comment: What does ESM stand for?

Comment: @J.M. ES6 modules

Comment: [ECMAScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

Comment: @J.M. - As str said, [ECMAScript modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html), but this link is to the Node.js documentation on using them (since you're using Node.js).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything I can do only with express?

The reason for doing two separate lines like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
```

instead of this:

```
const app = require('express')();
```

is that the `express` module has [other methods](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express) on it that are sometimes needed such as:

```
express.static(...)               // middleware for serving static files
express.json(...)                 // middleware for parsing json requests
express.urlencoded(...)           // middleware for parsing urlencoded requests
express.Router(...)               // constructor for a new Router object
```

Comment: @j.m. - It seems like this addresses what you were really trying to ask.  Is that right?